# Forgot to take my portion of the tips

Tags: salary, customer-service

I’m working at a store where we get tips and split it at the end of the night. The process is very informal and usually someone leaves your cut where you had been working. I’ve been here about a month. Tonight someone left my cut in a place that I’m not used to, but he did tell me. I forgot to pick it up before leaving. I’m wondering if there’s a way I can still get my portion of tips? A different shift of people will be working in the morning before I’m scheduled to come in.  It’s not really a big deal, usually it’s less than $10 per person. I could just tell my manager "I forgot to pickup my tips last night" but I really do value the relationship I have with all the coworkers (in the sense I don't want to bother people over something very minor).

EDIT: I forgot to say that my cut of the tips was left in the tip jar so it may be mixed up and I don't want to take the tips away from the morning staff.

Comment: So go in, say "I forgot to pick up my tips", and take the money.  Or if you think it makes you look dishonest, then don't.  This hinges on a lot of details that we don't know.  Not really an answerable question here, sorry.

Comment: You forgot to take your tips, why would it affect your relationship with co-workers?

Comment: @MaskedMan: If not enough time is spent among the people working there, a different shift crew can get second thoughts if you just swing in, grab some money from the place and giving the line "forgot my tips". In case of money it is always important to make it in a clear way, and there is not enough details to make a fitting answer.

Comment: @Sonic unless the place he is grabbing the money from is the cash register or safe, I think he should be fine with just popping in and picking it up - if anyone questions him, he could simply acknowledge them, tell the duty manager "I just popped in for my tips but some people are unsure about my just taking some money - could you hang on to this money in question and I will clear it up with my duty manager later on?"

Comment: Final close vote cast. As @dan1111 mentioned this is a very company-dependent kind of thing. We can't tell whether your coworkers are likely to object to you taking your share out of the tip jar or if they'd consider it no big deal. Only you can reasonably make that call.

Comment: @Lilienthal then what is the point of this site as you could say for any question "you can't be sure how people will react"

Comment: @HarlyK See [help] and [meta] for descriptions on the types of questions we can answer here. In this case the critical element is that you're not asking "when faced with [situation] how can I accomplish [goal]?", which is answerable but rather "how will [team] in [company] react to [action]?". The point is that we don't know your workplace or colleagues and hence we can't give constructive answers beyond "ask someone you trust at work / your manager what you can do".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the place is closed, then ring the morning shift manager early and explain and ask if they can hold the money for you somewhere. Hopefully it's still there and nothing untoward happens to it (in which case write it off to experience).

10 bucks is ten bucks, plenty of times I've wished I had an extra $10 in my pocket.

Comment: I guess that's it, it seems so petty to call the store and bother the manager over less than $10

Comment: Feel free to throw ten bucks at me if you're so rich, assuming it's USD it's over 20% more than the minimum wage take home for a whole days work here.

Comment: if I understand you, your minimum wage is less than $10 a day? that is ridiculous.

Comment: @HarlyK it's true enough, here and in many other places. Calculating in my head quickly the min wage here is about 90 cents US an hour, maybe slightly less.

Comment: Getting stiffed intentionally or unintentionally in a tip-sharing scenario is very common. The time to deal with it is on the night it happens. By the next day, money is (literally or figuratively) in other people's pockets and the OP needs to put him/herself into the embarrassing position of extracting money from someone. Best to take it as a 10-dollar lesson and move on, forget it happened but be extra vigilant the next time.

Comment: I went in the next morning and spoke with the manager and picked it up.

Comment: Good for you mate, money is money (Y) Glad it worked out.

Answer (score 1):

Turning my comment into an answer...

You should be fine with simply popping in, picking the money up and explaining to anyone who asks what you are doing.

If you do get some forcible questions about your actions, questions which are bordering on accusations, then you simply acknowledge them as an employee being careful and take appropriate action - I would suggest going directly to the duty manager, explaining the situation, tell them that some people feel uneasy about what you are doing, ask the duty manager to hang on to the money and pass it on to your duty manager and say you will clear the issue up with your duty manager later on.

That keeps it all nice and open.

Comment: I should have mentioned that the guy who divided the tips tonight, left my portion in the tip jar. So it may be mixed up by the time I get in the morning.

Comment: @HarlyK well, that adds an entirely different angle to the issue... call the place at or before opening time and explain the situation to the duty manager, they should realise that there shouldnt be that amount of tip money at opening time and put it to one side for you.

Comment: How so? I did say he left it in an unusual spot...

Comment: @HarlyK an unusual spot could be "behind the bar, by the tequila bottles, where no tip money is ever left".  Which is entirely different to "in the tip jar, where its not immediately obvious as an individual share and it also doesn't stand out as unusual".